# Make Python2.5 failed on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, make

for some reason I need to install Python2.5 on Ubuntu 13.04. I tried to install it from source. However the make operation is failed with the following error:

```
    gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DSVNVERSION=\"`LC_ALL=C svnversion .`\" -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
    gcc: error： directory"：No such file or directory
    make: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] error 1
```

I googled about it but still don't know what happened. How could I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you run `LC_ALL=C svnversion .`?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Unversioned directory. I downloaded the source from Python website in a tar ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the build scripts as they only test if subversion is installed but not if the source code is actually using subversion.

Running

```
SVNVERSION=not-found ./configure
```

instead of just

```
./configure
```

before you run `make` seems to be a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed can solve my problem. Also I've found that this is a Python issue with Subversion 1.7 [issue6094](http://bugs.python.org/issue6094)

Answer (score 2):

Temporary workaround:

```
SVNVERSION="Unversioned directory" ./configure --prefix=/home/jeff/py25 -- enable-shared
```

Visit [issue6094](http://bugs.python.org/issue6094)